# Subdomain returns cgi error

Tags: apache, subdomain

I have created a virtual host with a subdomain, the subdomain's dns is pointed at the server. When I visit the subdomain I get the following error: 
The requested URL "/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi" was not found on this server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ServerAlias test.domain.com

    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public/domain.com
    <Directory "/var/www/public/domain.com">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /error.log
    CustomLog /access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried using *.domain.com as well.
If I use a local host to point domain.com at the server it works as expected, but using localhost does not allow the subdomain to work in either case.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that my syntax is correct, chrome's dns caching had cached the bad page. Using firefox worked.